# Ether object is not callable-python

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to write a code for `nslookup` using scapy. When I run it, it says:

> TypeError: 'Ether' object is not callable

It points to this line: `print(ans(ether(ip.src)))`.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you googled the error you got?

Comment: I did, but I could not find a specific answer to what I was looking for

Comment: can you show the code? seems like ether object is already instanced and don't have the __call__ method in his class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Scapy syntax is off. It should be

`print(ans[IP].src)`

instead of

`print(ans(ether(ip.src)))`

I don't see how the Ether part has anything to do with this. I think you have a different approach than me when writing nslookup.